# Very bad picture quality when connects my laptop to my 42" LG plasma Tv

Tags: hdmi, plasma-tv

I need help on connecting my laptop to my plasma TV.
Here are my hardware specs:

1. Dell XPS M1330(display: 13.3 inch, 16:10, 1280x800)
2. LG PJ350 plasma TV (display: 42 inch, 16:09, 1024x768)

When I connect my laptop to the TV, the picture quality is very bad. I have tried connected my laptop to my dad's 50" Panasonic TV, the picture is perfect. So, I am pretty sure my laptop is ok.

Here are the reasons that I think might the cause:

1. Resolution setting on my laptop(I've tried 1024x768, 1168x666, 1280x800, 1980x1080 and many more), but no luck.
2. I bought a cheap HDMI cable. I don't know if the cable has that much effect on this.
3. The TV is just defective.
4. The specs on my laptop just doesn't go with the TV.

If the picture quality can't be improved, I am thinking to return the TV.
Please advise if there is something I can do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the picture look like for it to be "very bad"? Is it digital artefacts? Snow?

Comment: Bas as the picture is not sharp. I can barely read the text on a webpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any TV not designed to work as a monitor will be a little blurry due to how they work, and it's a 16:9 resolution so any non-16:9 resolution will look pretty awful.

That particular screen has a native resolution of 1366 X 768, which will be the sharpest picture it will produce. Try setting it to that resolution before anything else.

Comment: Any resolution that isn't the native resolution of the TV will look bad in my experience, let alone stuff that's not the same aspect ratio.

Comment: @Matthew Yeah, any non-native will look bad (which is why I mentioned trying the native resolution), but a non-correct ratio will look even worse.

Comment: Ok ok, at least I know I don't need to get another HDMI cable. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

plasma TVs have relatively low resolution for their size - so the 'pixels' are HUGE - its even worse on my dad's TV which is 800x600. This results in things not looking as sharp.

Its really not as much an issue with the TV as TVs and monitors being optimised for different things.

Comment: =( The picture quality between my dad's and my TV is just huge.

Comment: is your dad's tv an LCD? what resolution?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://reviews.plasmatvbuyingguide.com/plasmatvreviews/lg-pj350-calibration.html), the edges are a bit blurry for that TV. I don't know if that's the cause of the problem you're seeing, but it might be an indicator.

Comment: I can accept if it's a bit blurry, but mine is horrible.

Comment: @Dreteh TV's are built to display images, usually moving images. If things are a bit blurry and the pixels aren't defined, then that's usually a *good* thing. TV's aren't designed to be monitors.

Comment: But aren't monitors built to display images or moving images too =)

Answer (score -1):

Try to reset all picture settings on your TV to default, I had this issue and that fixed it.